# Nearest neighbor method for class identification problem

Tags: machine-learning

I have training data that consists of dates and times of different people entering the building.

Test data consists of dates and times and their pseudonyms instead of their real names. I need to correctly 1-1 map these people to their pseudonyms.

I'm planning to memorize behavior of each of these people in the form of a discrete probability distribution, given when they've been entering the building. And then for each of the pseudonyms, calculate the pseudonym's discrete probability distribution, and then calculate in some sense the distance between it and each of the real people's distribution, and choose the person with the least distance.

I assume that every person can have their own very different inherent distribution. I also assume that every person has a normal variation to their exact time of arrival (being late or early), with the same (maybe different) variance.

Would this simple nearest-neighbor classifier be optimal? Is it correct to call it a nearest-neighbor classifier? I think it should be optimal in the sense of providing correct solution, but might not be optimal from memory and execution time standpoint, but it doesn't matter much to me right now. Would love a second opinion

Answer (score 0):

> Would this simple nearest-neighbor classifier be **optimal**?

No, clearly not.
You did not introduce a loss function by which we could gauge optimality.
Absent that criterion, there is no way to evaluate such a claim.

> ... and then calculate in some sense the distance between it and each of the real people's distribution ...

> Is it correct to call it a nearest-neighbor classifier?

Sure, that sounds about right.
Though the "in some sense" appears to lack the rigor of,
say, an "L^2 norm" definition.

Each person is different.

Some people have an office arrival schedule governed by weekday vs weekend,
for example whether they're scheduled for work, or for a meeting,
or whether they have childcare responsibilities.
Some people will have schedules that have extra constraints on, say,
Tuesdays and Thursdays, due to recurring events outside of work.
Federal holidays can disturb people's schedules.
Your model has an opportunity to learn such details,
aggregated over the entire group or per-worker.
Size of available train + test datasets is likely to be the biggest constraint.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I was thinking to calculate distance by calculating the integral of P(X)-P(ps), where X is real person from test data, and ps is a pseudonym.
***********

But shouldn't this difference between different people make nearest-neighbor classifier more optimal compared to other classifiers? In theory, but not with this integral loss function, perhaps.
I think you're saying that given my integral loss function, I will lose those differences and my classifier will work very poorly. I see it now. Perhaps, I could choose a better loss function?